# Date formula embeded

Tags: worksheet-function

I am trying to embed a date formula inside a countif formula, but all I get are errors saying that I can not use < or =. Here is the formula I have now.   =COUNTIFS(M5:M200,"<=11/14/16")
I want to change the hard quoted date to take todays date less 730 days and see how many of my dates are equal to or less than that. I do not want to have to change it every day.  Any ideas?

Comment: you could do it this complicated way: add 730 in a cell, add a column which will calculate the difference today minus days in static cell where you put 730 in and minus the m cell, so you will get the difference in days and then count all cells which are bigger or smaller than 0

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
=COUNTIFS(M5:M200,"<="&(TODAY()-730))
```

This works because dates are stored as integer days (+ fractional time as proportion of day). The `&` causes the result of the arithmetic calculation to be implicitly converted to text.

Note that, like your original formula, this will give possibly unexpected results if there is a time element in the column `M` cells, since the `<=` will not match dates exactly 730 days ago for any time after midnight. This is answered by:

```
=COUNTIFS(M5:M200,"<"&(TODAY()-729))
```

If you need to take account of a leap year in the last two years, you will need the more elaborate:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A3,"<="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-2,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())))
```

I am not quite sure what will happen if you invoke this function on 29th February. I *think* that it will produce the same count as on the following day.